# Access ajax data outside datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a simple datatable instance:

```
var table = $("#table-elem").DataTable({
        ...
        "ajax": {
            "url":Services.apiUrl,
            "dataSrc": "data"
        },
        ...
})
```

I need to access the "data" that was returned in ajax call. How can I do that? Expecting something like:

```
var ajaxJson = table.ajax.data()
//play with ajaxJson
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.json()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
table.on('xhr', function() {
  var ajaxJson = table.ajax.json();
  alert(ajaxJson.data.length + ' row(s) were loaded');
});
```

Gives back the last loaded data, as per the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.json())